# Using HashSet and Contains to return TRUE if one or many fields is in the hash

Tags: c#, hashset

I am wondering if it is possible to use a HashSet and make the method *Contains* to return true if one of the field is in the hash for a giving object.

This is an example of what I would like

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    HashSet<Product> hash = new HashSet<Product>();

    // Since the Id is the same, both products are considered to be the same even if the URI is not the same
    // The opposite is also true.  If the URI is the same, both products are considered to be the same even if the Id is not the same
    Product product1 = new Product("123", "www.test.com/123.html");
    Product product2 = new Product("123", "www.test.com/123.html?lang=en");

    hash.Add(product1);

    if (hash.Contains(product2))
    {
        // I want the method "Contains" to return TRUE because one of the field is in the hash
    }
}
```

Here is the definition of the class Product

```
public class Product
{
    public string WebId
    public string Uri

    public Product(string Id, string uri)
    {
        WebId = Id;
        Uri = uri;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
        if (obj.GetType() != typeof(Product)) return false;
        return Equals((Product)obj);
    }

    public bool Equals(Product obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;

        if (String.Equals(WebId, obj.WebId) || String.Equals(Uri, obj.Uri)) 
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            int hash = 17;

            hash = hash * 23 + WebId.GetHashCode();
            hash = hash * 23 + Uri.GetHashCode();
            return hash;
        }
    }
}
```

When I run my program, the method *Contains* only runs *GetHashCode* and never the method *Equals*.  Hence, the method *Contains* return FALSE.

How can I make my HashSet to return TRUE for the example above ?  Should I be using a Dictionary instead and add each fields to the dictionary ?

Comment: Your `Equals` and/or `GetHashCode` implementation is broken. If two objects are equal then they *must* have the same hashcode. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode.aspx

Comment: The reason why your equality logic makes no sense is this. Equality is a transitive operation. If a==b and b==c then it means a==c as well. In your case this is not true and that's the reason why you can't make it work with GetHashCode. Example, consider three objects a, b and c: (a.Id=1, a.Url="a"), (b.Id=1, b.Url="b") and (c.Id=2, c.Url="b"). In this example, using your equality logic, the following is true: a==b and also b==c, which means this should also be true: a==c, but it's not.

Answer (score 5):

Your GetHashCode() implementation isn't guaranteed to return the same value for two objects that are equal.  Since you only require a match on, say, WebId.  The Uri then screws up the hash code.  Or the other way around.  You cannot fix this, other than by returning 0.  That's going to kill the HashSet<> perf, lookup will be O(n) instead of O(1).

Answer (score 2):

In a recent project we had the same problem, where the class's Equals() implementation was logical ORing properties to determine equality. To do a quick Contains() we built a number of IEqualityComparer with each one checking ONE property. You need one for each property that is ORed in your equality check.

```
    class WebIdComparer : IEqualityComparer<Product>
    {
        public bool Equals(Product x, Product y)
        {
            return Equals(x.WebId, y.WebId);
        }

        public int GetHashCode(Product obj)
        {
            unchecked
            {
                return obj.WebId.GetHashCode();
            }
        }
    }

    class UriComparer : IEqualityComparer<Product>
    {
        public bool Equals(Product x, Product y)
        {
            return Equals(x.Uri, y.Uri);
        }

        public int GetHashCode(Product obj)
        {
            unchecked
            {
                return obj.Uri.GetHashCode();
            }
        }
    }
```

Then, create one hashtable per IEqualityComparer, passing in the comparer to the constructor. insert your collection into each hashtable, then for each item you want to test, do a contains() on each hashtable and OR the result. So For example:

```
var uriHashTable = new HashSet<Product>(existingProducts, new UriComparer());
var webIdHashTable = new HashSet<Product>(existingProducts, new WebIdComparer());

foreach (var newProduct in newProducts)
{
    if (uriHashTable.Contains(newProduct) || webIdHashTable.Contains(newProduct))
        //then it is equal to an existing product according to your equals implementation
}
```

Obviously this method suffers from using quite a bit more memory than the IEnumerable.Contains() method, needs more memory for every property that is ORed in your equals implementation.

Comment: Your solution also suffers from the same symptom as the OP's equality logic. It's not transitive and it may happen in your case that if a==b and b==c that you'll expect a==c to be true as well, but it doesn't happen. One reason for that could be that objects a and b are equal based on the first condition, and objects b and c are equal, based on the second condition, while objects a and c don't satisfy neither conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Does it fit in your program design to use a lamba inside the `Contains` method call? It is the most straightforward way I can think of to achieve what you want.

```
if (hash.Contains(p => p.WedId == product2.WebId))
{
    // "Contains" will now return TRUE because the WebId matches
}
```

Comment: But note that this will be O(n) rather than O(1), since it uses `Enumerable.Contains` rather than `HashSet<T>.Contains`. Something like this is probably the best option though, since there doesn't seem to be any way to correctly meet the OP's requirements in O(1).

Comment: I get the compile error of `Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'Product' because it is not a delegate type`